# Cannot create a folder on the partition that was just created within a DSC script

Tags: powershell, dsc

I'm trying to use DSC to format drives and create a certain folder structure on newly formatted drives.

Right after I've created a partition, formatted a disk and gave it a drive letter I'm trying to create a folder using the new disk path however I'm receiving `Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'K' does not exist` types of errors on `New-Item` call. This code is an example of one executed within a `Script` DSC:

```
$someDiskNumber = 3 # for the sake of testing

Initialize-Disk -Number $someDiskNumber -PartitionStyle GPT -PassThru
$partition = New-Partition -DiskNumber $someDiskNumber -UseMaximumSize -DriveLetter 'K'
Format-Volume -Partition $partition -FileSystem NTFS -AllocationUnitSize 65536 -NewFileSystemLabel "san-root" -Confirm:$False
New-Item -Path "K:\Test" -ItemType Directory -Force -ErrorAction Stop
```

How do I make the DSC script "rediscover" the new volume to allow running `New-Item` for it?

What I have tried (no success):

- Running `Update-Disk -DiskNumber $someDiskNumber` after the `Format-Volume` call
- Running `Update-HostStorageCache` after the `Format-Volume` call
- Add a `while` loop after the `Format-Volume` call to wait for `Test-Path "K:\"` to return `True` (it looped forever)

P.S. I am aware of the `xStorage` DSC module but unfortunately I cannot use it due to limitations (irrelevant to the question).

Comment: Is `xStorage` does what you want but you can't use it, you can still look at its source code to determine _how_ it does what you want. Have you tried that?

Comment: @briantist I'm not sure `xStorage` does what I want. The issue I'm having is not with creating the mountpoint (which `xStorage` does), it's the last line (`New-Item`) which is not part of `xStorage`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48430618/trouble-accessing-newly-attached-disk-in-dsc-on-an-azure-vm/48447113#48447113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured an answer five minutes after trying StackOverflow. Adding the command below will force PowerShell to refresh the cache and get the missing drives.

`$null = Get-PSDrive`

Comment: Good find! I haven't been in this situation before but I'll remember this.

Comment: there is a special dsc resource for that, i think. overall that bug is pretty retarded. xWaitForDrive or something like that