# Trouble Accessing Newly attached disk in DSC on an azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, dsc

I have an issue with a DSC config i'm trying to use to install and run a mongo service on an Azure VM.

When the DSC runs on the initial deployment of the VM, the secondary disk 'F' is attached and formatted successfully, however... i receive an error when trying to create directories on the new disk:

```
Error message: \"DSC Configuration 'Main' completed with error(s).
Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'F' does not exist. 
The PowerShell DSC resource '[Script]SetUpDataDisk' with SourceInfo 'C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\\2.73.0.0\\DSCWork\\MongoDSC.0\\MongoDSC.ps1::51::2::Script' threw one or more non-terminating errors while running the Set-TargetResource functionality.
```

Here is my DSC script :

```
Configuration Main
{

Param ( [string] $nodeName )

Import-DscResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration
Import-DscResource -ModuleName xStorage

Node $nodeName
{
    xWaitforDisk Disk2
    {
        DiskId = 2
        RetryIntervalSec = 60
        RetryCount = 60
    }
    xDisk FVolume
    {
        DiskId = 2
        DriveLetter = 'F'
        FSLabel = 'MongoData'
        DependsOn = "[xWaitforDisk]Disk2"
    }
    Script SetUpDataDisk{
        TestScript ={
            return Test-Path "f:\mongoData\"
        }
        SetScript ={
            #set up the directories for mongo

            $retries = 0
            Do{
                $mountedDrive = Get-Volume | Where DriveLetter -eq 'F'
                if($mountedDrive -eq $null)
                {
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
                    $retries = $retries + 1
                }
            }While(($mountedDrive -eq $null) -and ($retries -lt 60))

            $dirName = "mongoData"
            $dbDirName = "db"
            $logDirName = "logs"

            ##! ERROR THROWN FROM THESE LINES
            New-Item -Path "F:\$dirName" -ItemType Directory
            New-Item -Path "F:\$dirName\$dbDirName" -ItemType Directory
            New-Item -Path "F:\$dirName\$logDirName" -ItemType Directory
        }
        GetScript = {@{Result = "SetUpDataDisk"}}
        DependsOn = "[xDisk]FVolume"
    }
  }
}
```

The annoying thing is that if i run the deployment again everything works with no errors, i have put a loop in to try and wait for the disk to be ready but this still throws the error. I'm very new to DSC so any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Found the answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48410973/cannot-create-a-folder-on-the-partition-that-was-just-created-within-a-dsc-scrip?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems **xDiskAccessPath** can be used for that:

```
<#
    .EXAMPLE
        This configuration will wait for disk 2 to become available, and then make the disk available as
        two new formatted volumes mounted to folders c:\SQLData and c:\SQLLog, with c:\SQLLog using all
        available space after c:\SQLData has been created.
#>
Configuration Example
{

    Import-DSCResource -ModuleName xStorage

    Node localhost
    {
        xWaitforDisk Disk2
        {
             DiskId = 2
             RetryIntervalSec = 60
             RetryCount = 60
        }

        xDiskAccessPath DataVolume
        {
             DiskId = 2
             AccessPath = 'c:\SQLData'
             Size = 10GB
             FSLabel = 'SQLData1'
             DependsOn = '[xWaitForDisk]Disk2'
        }

        xDiskAccessPath LogVolume
        {
             DiskId = 2
             AccessPath = 'c:\SQLLog'
             FSLabel = 'SQLLog1'
             DependsOn = '[xDiskAccessPath]DataVolume'
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/PowerShell/xStorage/blob/dev/Modules/xStorage/Examples/Resources/xDiskAccessPath/1-xDiskAccessPath_InitializeDataDiskWithAccessPath.ps1